# Atom creating double angle brackets

Tags: element, brackets, html5boilerplate

Why does my Atom makes double brackets when I enter  auto input on, I have installed packages for Atom.

[double brackets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ea7mk.gif)

Comment: My friend you really need to flesh out this question with in-text examples. Your link is really good and adds clarity but it looks like a very low effort post and as such, I doubt most of the 28 visitors you have had, have even glanced at the link. Given the one-sentence question I assumed the link would just lead to a Wikipedia page of what brackets are. Video/gif is cool but it really helps to keep things on-site as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to type the brackets. Just type what you want to do, for example `script` and it will create the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  
</script>
```